# Getting User.Identity.Name after AspNet OpenAuth Login via Web Forms Template

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am using Web Forms Template in VS2012 and looking at OpenAuth code.

I wish to store some external data after a successful external login, but during debug cannot see how to get hold of the logged in username during the code execution at these points after a valid external login -

ProcessProviderResult
  - if (OpenAuth.Login(authResult.Provider, authResult.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))

CreateAndLoginUser()
  - if (OpenAuth.Login(ProviderName, ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))

After these calls there is no User.Identity.Name and the username has not been authenticated, so how can I get the membershipusername?
It seems to be logged in after the redirect (do I really have to store something in a session and munge it in after redirect? I think I am doing it wrong).

What methods on OpenAuth.?? or equivalent do I need to call to get the username so I can then store my data as required.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.Identity.Name` will only be filled by the Forms Auth authentication provider on return (after the client has been redirected, as you point out).

But during the auth process, in the OpenAuth code before the redirect, the user name is simply represented by `AuthenticationResult.UserName` (ie: authResult.UserName in ExternalLoginLandingPage.aspx.cs).

Comment: Thanks for help @Simon Mourier.  I wonder if you could help me see the best way then to use this to tie the ExtraData to the "resulting" (after redirect you clarified, is this a bug in OAuth) membershipuser? do I really have to manually look in the UsersOpenAuthAccounts table using the AuthResult? Any idea why there is no method on OpenAuth to allow lookup with this? or am I missing a step?

Comment: Not sure to understand your problem here. The user name is filled during the processing of ProcessProviderResult, as a result of the call to OpenAuth.VerifyAuthentication(redirectUrl) in https://github.com/rustd/SocialLoginASPNET/blob/master/IntegrateSocialLogin/ExternalLoginLandingPage.aspx.cs; if you need it before the redirect, then you need to modify that ProcessProviderResult method.

Comment: I do not think AuthenticationResult.UserName is the same as membershipusername, from the docs - Gets an (insecure, non-unique) alias for the user that the user should recognize as himself/herself. Remarks: This alias may come from the Provider or may be derived by the relying party if the Provider does not supply one.  It is not guaranteed to be unique ...
If we wanted to store some extra data it looks like we would have to use the keys AuthenticationResult.Provider and AuthenticationResult.ProviderUserId and then somehow link them back to Membership username after the repost, feels "hacky" ..

Comment: Maybe this will work - Store the ExtraData in an UsersOpenAuthExtraData table with AuthenticationResult.Provider and AuthenticationResult.ProviderUserId as the compound keys (or FK to UsersOpenAuthAccounts) and then on redirect, use the User.Identity.Username to look up any external accounts, and then use OpenAuthAccountData to look the record up and away we go? (or something along those lines)

Comment: Looks like no other takers on this question and the end result is basically roll your own, so will mark as answer (with a few additions the core VS2012 template could cover off the final 10% of this for a clean and easy out of box solution), I will "try" to post my solution when I get to it, if we can update the source code for this dll that would be even nicer.

Comment: @WickedW how did you ever solve this? I think I need the same thing: when a user logs in successfully for the first time I want to store some additional membership data (e.g. birthdate, favorite food). Also I want to be able to retrieve that when the user logs in for a second time.

Comment: @Flo sorry its been so long since looked at this I cannot give you useful answer as the project never progressed passed this point, think the clue is possibly in the comment from Nov 22 21:30 ...